# Removing elements from Pandas Series of lists

Tags: python, string, pandas, list, series

I've been searching for solutions and hints from the site, but couldn't find issue directly related with my case.

I have scraped text data from various sites and have split the text by using `str.split('\n')`. The text contains a lot of '\n' and splitting this way made it pretty desirable. (Please let me know if this approach is too bad.)

```
df['scrape']
0       \nWebsite:\n\n\n\nVisit\n\n \nWhite paper:\n\n...
1       \nWebsite:\n\n\n\nVisit\n\n \nWhite paper:\n\n...
2       \nWebsite:\n\n\n\nVisit\n\n \nWhite paper:\n\n...
3       \nWebsite:\n\n\n\nVisit\n\n \nWhite paper:\n\n...
4       \nWebsite:\n\n\n\nVisit\n\n \nWhite paper:\n\n...
5       \nWebsite:\n\n\n\nVisit\n\n \nWhite paper:\n\n...
```

The result was a Pandas Series of lists – all elements are list of strings.

```
df['split'] = df['scrape'].str.split('\n')
0       [, Website:, , , , Visit, ,  , White paper:, ,...
1       [, Website:, , , , Visit, ,  , White paper:, ,...
2       [, Website:, , , , Visit, ,  , White paper:, ,...
3       [, Website:, , , , Visit, ,  , White paper:, ,...
4       [, Website:, , , , Visit, ,  , White paper:, ,...
5       [, Website:, , , , Visit, ,  , White paper:, ,...
6       [, Website:, , , , Visit, ,  , White paper:, ,...
```

I want to get rid of None element (‘’ and ‘ ‘) on each list.

I tried looping:

```
for i in series:
    While ‘’ in i:
        i.remove(‘’)
```

Above code works with some arbitrary example I made, but with my real data it produces an error.

```
for i in df['split']:
...     while '' in i:
...         i.remove('')
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable
```

I'm not sure why I am getting an error with my data. Could get get some advice on this? Thanks!

Comment: Don't store lists in a Series

Comment: What's the suggestion for this case then, if I don't store lists in a Series?

Comment: Solution Thanks to Toby's idea : 
def remover(list):
    return [s for s in list if s !='' and s != ' ']
df['new'] = df['split'].apply(remover)   With this method you don't need to drop NaN values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use list comprehension:

```
new_series = [s for s in series if s!='' and s!=' ' and s!=None]
```

To apply the list comprehension to each element in a Pandas Series of lists (essentially a list of lists), you need to nest the list comprehension like this:

```
new_series = [[s for s in element if s!='' and s!=' ' and s!=None] for element in series]
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I tried 
series = [s for s in df['split'] if s!='' and s!=' ']  and still it contains '' and ' ' values.

Comment: Do you need to add None criteria also? See my updated example

Comment: Still it doesn't work... tried converting it into list of lists too. Your suggestion yields one big list collapsed into, but I do have to keep those separate.

Comment: Ah ok I think I understand, you want to apply the list comprehension to each list in the series (essentially a list of lists). If I understand correctly this should work: `[[s for s in x if s!='' and s!=' ' and s!=None] for x in series]`

Comment: Thanks for keep updating. This answer looks like what I want, but honestly don't know why it makes error still..
    [[s for s in x if s!='' and s!=' ' and s!=None] for x in df['split']]

>>> [[s for s in x if s!='' and s!=' ' and s!=None] for x in df['split']]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: It's strange that for individual list element, your suggestion works. I.E.
[ s for s in df['split'][0] if s != '' and s != ' '] works. However it generates ValueError when it is nested

Comment: Is it possible that `df["split"]` contains some values which aren't lists? The error saying `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable` suggests that maybe there are NaN values in some of the rows. In which case you could use `dropna` to remove those rows first, then apply the list comprehension.

Comment: Oh!! Thank you so much. It worked. You made my day :)

Comment: No problem, happy to help